# why am I getting this error during a build ? mentions something about cannot debug

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am trying to run/debug a project and im getting this error. I have never seen this before!

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Side_Project.exe" to
>   "bin\Debug\Side_Project.exe". The process cannot access the file
>   'bin\Debug\Side_Project.exe' because it is being used by another
>   process.  Side_Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states it cannot copy the file because its in use. its as simple as that.

- Make sure the file isn't actually running, Check Task Manager.
- Make sure it isnt being locked by your virus checker.
- Also try restarting visual studio

If worst comes to worst restart your pc

Job done, happy debugging

Answer (score 0):

This means the program is still opened. Check if it is running in the background, open task manager or force kill it with Command Prompt

command:

> C:>Taskkill /IM Side_Project.exe /F

or by PID

> C:>Taskkill /PID (PID HERE) /F

View your PID by opening a list of running tasks with

> C:>tasklist

See if that works.